# Delete records from listView in Android and MYSQL

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

i'm trying to solve this problem, the code seem working but i've no clue why it doesn't delete the record in DB, so i'll post my java code, the first one will include the listView in Android.
The first AsyncTask is to download and populate the listView and the second one to eliminate record

```
public class ptClienteScheda extends AppCompatActivity 
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pt_cliente_scheda);
    String idC= getIntent().getStringExtra("idC");
    /*PROVA PER ID
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ID cliente" + idC,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     */
    URL paginaURL = null;
    //invio il dato username che mi servirà per la query
    try
    {
        paginaURL = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/gymHome/schedaPtCliente.php?idC=" + idC);
        HttpURLConnection client = (HttpURLConnection) paginaURL.openConnection();

    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //stato+=connessioneHttp.ScaricaTesto();
    new ScaricaTestoTask().execute("http://10.0.2.2/gymHome/schedaPtCliente.php?idC="+ idC);


}

protected void popolaListView(String righeCLiente)
{
    //Toast.makeText(this, righeCLiente, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    //popolo la listView
    String[] nameproducts = righeCLiente.split("\\+");
    // definisco un ArrayList
    final ArrayList<String> listp = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < nameproducts.length; ++i)
    {
        listp.add(nameproducts[i]);
    }
    // recupero la lista dal layout
    final ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvptc);

    // creo e istruisco l'adattatore
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listp);

    // inietto i dati
    mylist.setAdapter(adapter);



    mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adattatore, final View componente, int pos, long id){
            // recupero il titolo memorizzato nella riga tramite l'ArrayAdapter
             String titoloriga = (String) adattatore.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            String[]titr=titoloriga.split(" ");
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Ho cliccato sull'elemento con titolo" + titoloriga,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             String idC=titr[1];
            TextView tw= findViewById(R.id.twID);
            tw.setText(idC);

            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    ptClienteScheda.this);
            adb.setTitle("Elimina elemento:");
            adb.setMessage("Sei sicuro di voler eliminare " +listp.get(pos)+ "?");
             final int posizioneDaRimuovere = pos;
            adb.setNegativeButton("Annulla", null);
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    new eliminaEsercizioTask().execute();
                    adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(posizioneDaRimuovere));

                }
            });
            adb.show();
        }
    });

}


public void btAggiungi(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(ptClienteScheda.this, aggiungiEsercizio.class);
    //passo il dato all'activity

    startActivity(intent);
}


public class ScaricaTestoTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
    {

        return connessioneHttp.ScaricaTesto(urls[0]);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {

        String righeCliente;
        righeCliente=connessioneHttp.parseRigheSchedaPt(result);
        popolaListView(righeCliente);

        String gigi=connessioneHttp.parseclienteRighePT(result);
        TextView tw=findViewById(R.id.twper2);
        tw.setText("Sei nella scheda del cliente : "+ gigi);
    }
}

public class eliminaEsercizioTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        TextView tw2=findViewById(R.id.twID);
        String idc= (String) tw2.getText();
        return connessioneHttp.deleteRecord(idc);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {

        TextView risultato=findViewById(R.id.twres);
        String res=result;
        risultato.setText(res);


    }
}
```

}

and here you have the other class deleteRecord that connects to a PHP already tested

```
public static String deleteRecord(String id)
{
    String result = "";
    URL paginaURL = null;
    try
    {
        paginaURL = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/gymHome/eliminaRighe.php?idEsercizio=" + id);
        HttpURLConnection client = (HttpURLConnection) paginaURL.openConnection();
        result+=" eliminato "+id;
        return result;
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    result+="NON ELIMINATO";
    return result;
}
```

The problem is that records are not deleted

posting PHP aswell ( ALREADY TESTED AND PHP WORKS )

```
<?php
        $user = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $db = 'gymhome';
        $host = 'localhost';
        $port=3306;
        $idEsercizio=$_GET['idEsercizio'];
        try 
        {
         $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            // sql to delete a record
            $sql = "DELETE FROM righescheda WHERE righescheda.id='$idEsercizio' ";

        // use exec() because no results are returned
        $conn->exec($sql);

        echo "Record deleted successfully";
        }
            catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
        }

        $conn = null;

?>
```

Comment: Do you mean that the records are not deleted from PHP server end?

Comment: @KarthikCP yes PHP server end records aren't deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, i found the answer, i've just added to deleteRecord()
client.getResponseMessage();

and now it works.... I hope it will help someone else!